# Date type convert in SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis, sqldatatypes

Data set contains some 2020-02-01T19: 43: 03 data. How can I convert this to 2020-02-01 19:43:03 in SSIS. I tried (DT_DATE), (DT_DBDATE), (DT_DBTIMESTAMP) but it didn't.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly simple depending on the approach you wish to take :

1. You can create a script transformation task in which you can apply C# `String.Split` function to remove the `T`.
2. You can use SQL and use a `SUBSTRING` function which allow you to take the first part of the data till T and the next part of the datetime from T onwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Article 2 came to my mind, but I was thinking that maybe there is an easier way in SSIS and I was doing research. Thanks again.

Comment: @Umut Do not forget to mark it as the answer if it answers your question.